# Do you know how to make my Summary function works properly? Because it keeps giving me the value 0

Tags: c

So I want to sum all of the price in my Summary function but I keep getting 0 for the value of *totalprice*. I've
tried changing the void into int but no luck. or maybe I did it in the wrong way. This program is to know the total of the electronic devices' electricity cost so it should be able to sum all the price of each device. I appreciate the help.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void countAC(int PK)
{
    float durationAC;
    float priceAC;
    int qttAC;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationAC);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttAC);
    if (PK==1){
        priceAC=durationAC*qttAC*400*1467/1000;
    }
    else if (PK==2){
        priceAC=durationAC*qttAC*600*1467/1000;
    }
    else if (PK==3){
        priceAC=durationAC*qttAC*840*1467/1000;
    }
    else if (PK==4){
        priceAC=durationAC*qttAC*540*1467/1000;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
    }
    printf("AC(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceAC);
}

void AC()
{
    int PK;
    printf("AC Types :\n");
    printf("1. 1/2 PK\n");
    printf("2. 3/4 PK\n");
    printf("3. 1 PK\n");
    printf("4. Inverter\n");
    printf("What types of AC do you use? ");
    scanf("%d",&PK);
    countAC(PK);
}

void countLamp(int LT)
{
    float durationLamp;
    float priceLamp;
    int qttLamp;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationLamp);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttLamp);
    if (LT==1){
        priceLamp=durationLamp*qttLamp*60/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (LT==2){
        priceLamp=durationLamp*qttLamp*42/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (LT==3){
        priceLamp=durationLamp*qttLamp*12/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (LT==4){
        priceLamp=durationLamp*qttLamp*10/1000*1467;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
    }
    printf("Lamp(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceLamp);
}

void Lamp()
{
    int LT;
    printf("Lamp Types :\n");
    printf("1. Standard\n");
    printf("2. Halogen\n");
    printf("3. CFL\n");
    printf("4. LED\n");
    printf("What types of Lamp do you use? ");
    scanf("%d",&LT);
    countLamp(LT);
}

void countFan(int FT)
{
    float durationFan;
    float priceFan;
    int qttFan;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationFan);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttFan);
    if (FT==1){
        priceFan=durationFan*qttFan*50/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (FT==2){
        priceFan=durationFan*qttFan*30/1000*1467;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
    }
    printf("Fan(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceFan);
}

void Fan()
{
    int FT;
    printf("Fan Types :\n");
    printf("1. Large Fan\n");
    printf("2. Small Fan\n");
    printf("What types of Fan do you use? ");
    scanf("%d",&FT);
    countFan(FT);
}

void countRef(int RT)
{
    float durationRef;
    float priceRef;
    int qttRef;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationRef);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttRef);
    if (RT==1){
        priceRef=durationRef*qttRef*125/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (RT==2){
        priceRef=durationRef*qttRef*80/1000*1467;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
    }
    printf("Refrigerator(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceRef);
}

void Ref()
{
    int RT;
    printf("Fan Types :\n");
    printf("1. Large Refrigerator\n");
    printf("2. Small Refrigerator\n");
    printf("What types of Refrigerator do you use? ");
    scanf("%d",&RT);
    countRef(RT);
}

void countTV(int TT)
{
    float durationTV;
    float priceTV;
    int qttTV;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationTV);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttTV);
    if (TT==1){
        priceTV=durationTV*qttTV*50/1000*1467;
    }
    else if (TT==2){
        priceTV=durationTV*qttTV*110/1000*1467;
    }
    else {
        printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
    }
    printf("Television(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceTV);
}
    
void TV()
{
    int TT;
    printf("TV Types :\n");
    printf("1. LED TV\n");
    printf("2. LCD TV\n");
    printf("What types of Television do you use? ");
    scanf("%d",&TT);
    countTV(TT);
}

void WM()
{
    float durationWM;
    float priceWM;
    int qttWM;
    printf("How long do you use it a day? (in hours)\n");
    scanf("%f",&durationWM);
    printf("How many do you use in a day? \n");
    scanf("%d",&qttWM);
    priceWM=durationWM*qttWM*245/1000*1467;
    printf("Washing Machine(s) electricity cost/day : Rp %f",priceWM);
}

void Menu()
{
  int menu_opt;
  printf("Electronic Devices :\n");
  printf("1. Air Conditioner\n");
  printf("2. Lamp\n");
  printf("3. Fan\n");
  printf("4. Refrigerator\n");
  printf("5. Television\n");
  printf("6. Washing Machine\n");
  printf("Please choose your electronic device : ");
  scanf("%d",&menu_opt);
  if(menu_opt==1){
    AC();
  }
  else if(menu_opt==2){
    Lamp();
  }
  else if(menu_opt==3){
    Fan();
  }
  else if(menu_opt==4){
    Ref();
  }
  else if(menu_opt==5){
    TV();
  }
  else if(menu_opt==6){
    WM();
  }
  else {
    printf("wait, that's illegal\n");
  }
}

void Summary(float priceAC,float priceLamp,float priceFan,float priceRef,float priceTV,float priceWM)
{
    float totalprice;
    totalprice=priceAC+priceLamp+priceFan+priceRef+priceTV+priceWM;
    printf("AC Electricity Cost In A Day : Rp %f\n",priceAC);
    printf("Total Electricity Cost : Rp %f\n",totalprice);
}

int main ()
{
  int run=1,choice;
  float priceAC,priceLamp,priceFan,priceRef,priceTV,priceWM,totalprice;
  char answer[5];
  char a[]="yes",b[]="no",c[]="Yes",d[]="No",e[]="YES",f[]="NO";
  printf ("Hi! In this program, you can predict your electricity cost.\nContinue? (type 'yes' to continue or 'no' to stop)\n");
  scanf ("%s", answer);
  if (strcmp(a,answer)==0||strcmp(c,answer)==0||strcmp(e,answer)==0)
  {
    do{
    Menu();
    printf("\nDo you want to add more device?\t1.Yes\t2.No\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    run=choice;
    }while(run==1);
    Summary(priceAC,priceLamp,priceFan,priceRef,priceTV,priceWM);
  }
  else if (strcmp(b,answer)==0||strcmp(d,answer)==0||strcmp(f,answer)==0)
  {
    printf("Okay, see you later!"); 
  }
  else 
  {
    printf ("Sorry, I don't understand what you say");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the main method where do you set the values?  float priceAC,priceLamp,priceFan,priceRef,priceTV,priceWM,totalprice;

Comment: The identifiers are given really bad names such as: `RT`, `LT`, `PK`, `FT`, etc. and it makes hard to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function `Summary(priceAC,priceLamp,priceFan,priceRef,priceTV,priceWM);` is printing always 0 is because inside your `int main()` you declare you variables:

```
   float priceAC,priceLamp,priceFan,priceRef,priceTV,priceWM,totalprice;
```

But you never assign them a value so, when you break the `do while` loop and reach `Summary` all the parameters you are passing to it don't have an actual value.

What you need to do to add in your `Summary` for the devices you are asking for in your `Menu()` is to save the value for each device on a variable and send that value to your `Summary()`.

That way you will the output you are looking for.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: The `Summary` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @KeithThompson I know `Summary` doesn't return anything. It just prints out the `totalprice` that's why he needs to assign the variables he is passing as arguments a value.

Comment: OK. Please reread the first sentence of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variables

```c
float priceAC, priceLamp, priceFan, priceRef, priceTV, priceWM, totalprice;
```

inside your main function and later sum them up calling

```c
Summary(priceAC, priceLamp, priceFan, priceRef, priceTV, priceWM);
```

but they are never assigned values because they are local variables.

For example, if you compute `priceAC` in `countAC`, it is a different `priceAC` than in the main function. You could use global variables to exchange these values between functions.